# Using jQuery to dynamically modifiy sharethis

Tags: jquery, sharethis

I have a webpage which creates a unique URL when a user presses a certian button. On this page I have the following

```
<span id="share-this">
    <span class='st_facebook_hcount' st_url="http://www.google.com" displayText='Facebook'></span>
    <span class='st_twitter_hcount' st_url="http://www.google.com" displayText='Tweet'></span>
    <span class='st_pinterest_hcount' st_url="http://www.google.com" displayText='Pinterest'></span>
    <span class='st_email_hcount' st_url="http://www.google.com" displayText='Email'></span>
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "myID", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
```

When the user presses the button the following happens

```
jQuery('#share-this span').attr("st_url", window.location.href);
```

I can see the url being changed to look link4life

```
<span class='st_twitter_hcount' st_url="http://www.thisisme.com/#id=1639874" displayText='Tweet'></span>
```

but whenn I click on the button it takes me back to google.

I have tried adding

```
stButtons.locateElements();
```

once the URL has been updated (on pressing the button), this does not work.

any suggestions would be great full.

If someone has an example of using addEntry method to add a share this count button that would be awesome.

Comment: I would think this whole process should be taken care of by the plugin itself?

Comment: @MelanciaUK you would think so, but its not the case !

Comment: So what's the point of using the plugin if it doesn't work?

Comment: @MelanciaUK there must be a way of achieving what I'm trying to do. I find it hard to believe that someone hasn't already had this issue.

Comment: Did you check the plugin website to see if there's any error reported? Maybe they provided a solution already.

Comment: Try this: `jQuery('#share-this span').prop("st_url", window.location.href);`

Comment: There's something mentioned in their support forum: http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/questions/790954-dynamically-update-the-a-button-s-properties#sthash.owpEW2gh.dpbs

Comment: @MelanciaUK yup tried that doesn't work :( !! I have also put this exact question on the plugins support page.

Comment: I think the way to go is to destroy the `widget` and re-create it every time the `URL` changes. Not a nice thing to do though.